# Boolean Algebra Union and Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

I was reading Code by Charles Petzold and i found myself struggling with the rules of sets.

On the 81th page it says :

> The commutative, associative, and distributive rules all hold for Boolean algebra. What's more, in
>   Boolean algebra the + operator is distributive over the x operator. This isn't true of conventional
>   algebra:
>
> W + (B x F) = (W + B) x (W + F)
>
> The union of white cats and black female cats is the same as the intersection of two unions: the union
>   of white cats and black cats, and the union of white cats and female cats. This is somewhat difficult to
>   grasp, but it works.

So i used Venn Diagrams to demonstrate my supposition for the first part of equation
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4kB5.jpg)

And the second
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vulSN.jpg)

My question is what does the C (filled blue) set contain? I hope that i filled that right. I  personally think , that **ALL white cats** and also **Cats that are female and black at the same time** I got it by the 1st diagram, but not the second. I just can't understand what the word "OR" means in this context. Please leave feedback on my 2nd diagram and correct if i am mistaken. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "OR" is set *union*: "Cats are either male or female" means that the set of **all** Cats is "made of" the set of male Cats "plus" (set union) the set of female Cats.

Comment: "AND" is set *intersection* : male Cats are both male and cats, i.e. they are the *intersection* of the set of **all** Cats with the set of all male "animals".

Comment: Your first Venn diagram must be redraw: W + (B x F) does not "cover " all Cats. We have also Black male Cats (that are neither White nor Black female).

Answer (score 0):

HINT

When using Venn diagrams you want each circle to represent a 'simple' or 'atomic' class of objects. So for example: 'cats' would be a simple category. Or: 'white things'.  But you really don't want to use 'things that are cat or black'.  Indeed, even 'white cats' is already a combination of 'things that are cat *and* that are white': you really want to leave out logical operations in your definition for a single circle. Indeed, you use intersection, union, etc. to think about 'and', 'or', etc.

So in your case: have circles for 'cats', 'white things' and 'black things', and try again.